# How to calculate duration between logs in Datadog?

Tags: logging, monitoring, datadog, splunk-query

Splunk has `transaction` command which can produce `duration` between logs grouped by id:

```
2020-01-01 12:12 event=START id=1
2020-01-01 12:13 event=STOP  id=1
```

as it is described on

- [Query for calculating duration between two different logs in Splunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61358636/query-for-calculating-duration-between-two-different-logs-in-splunk)
- [Splunk - duration between two different messages by guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551991/splunk-duration-between-two-different-messages-by-guid?rq=1)
- [transaction time between events](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/transaction-time-between-events/td-p/50279)

How to calculate duration between events in Datadog?

Comment: Did you ever find this out? I'm currently looking for a way to do this, with no luck!

Comment: @DaveLeverton - haven't found stardard way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [group queries to create transactions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/group/#transactions) that will automatically calculate the duration. This screenshot is an example of logs grouped into transactions by `CartId`.

[image: screenshot of Datadog log explorer group query]

Comment: now how can I figure out what is the Avg duration , Max Duration , p99 duration? Example: In your screenshot, for the last 4 hour average duration = (25+419+2)/3. Can datadog answer it when we `group queries to create transaction`?